# Selecting an item from a list in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'd need to pick an object in a bag containing `20` elements with attributes `c (color)` and `s (size)`. Both color and size are numbers (e.g. `c= {red = 256, black = 0, ... } = {256, 0, ...}`).
As in Python I'd use random.choice in numpy library, I found on the web that the corresponding function in Netlogo is the extension rnd.
Struggling along a possible solution, I did

**Edited:**

```
breed[people person]
people-own 
  [
   ball
   size
   color 
   bag
  ]    
to setup
      create-people 5
  [ set color gray
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask people[
  set bag [ ] ; 0 items
  ]
end
```

To create the balls:

```
to create-balls
  set color random 300 ; color
  set size random-float 5 ; size
  let this-ball self
  ask one-of people [ ; ask one of people to put the ball created into the bag
      set bag fput this-ball bag ; add ball to the bag
  ]
end
```

The code below should include the part of drawing:

```
to draw
ask one-of people [
 rnd:weighted-one-of bag [ ] ; I do not know what I'd write in the brackets
]
end
```

As you can easily see, I've many doubts about how to implement the code.
How can I select one item from the bag depending on its size (or color)?

Can you please help me out with it?

Comment: Please show us how you create the balls. Are they a breed of turtles (I assume so since you use `size` and `color`)? Why are you using a list for the bag instead of an agentset?

Comment: Balls are defined in people-own as size and color. Same for bag.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. No, definitely this is not what I want. I should consider people that can create a balls assigning a size and color, then put the balls into a list. One selected person should select randomly (as he is blind) a ball from the bag. I have not thought to have problems with both the parts (creation objects and extraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete model that creates people and balls as turtle agents and has 30 of the balls get chosen weighted by their size. It then opens an inspect window for the person who has chosen the most balls.

```
extensions [rnd]

breed [people person]
people-own [ my-balls ]

breed [balls ball]
balls-own [ chosen? ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-people 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set my-balls (turtle-set nobody)
  ]
  create-balls 50
  [ hide-turtle
    set size one-of [1 2 3 4 5]
    set color one-of [red white blue yellow]
    set chosen? false
  ]
  repeat 30 [draw-ball]
  inspect max-one-of people [count my-balls]
end

to draw-ball
  ask one-of people
  [ let bag-of-balls balls with [not chosen?]
    let choice rnd:weighted-one-of bag-of-balls [size]
    ask choice [set chosen? true]
    set my-balls (turtle-set my-balls choice)
  ]
end
```

Some things to notice:

1. There are NO lists in this code. There are situations where you should use lists. Common uses include memory where the order is important (eg you only want to keep track of the last 5 other people seen) or where the same agent can appear multiple times. And the list commands are very powerful. However, unless you need a list then you should use agentsets.
2. Each person has their own bag called 'my-balls' that contains the balls they select. That is initialised as a turtle-list as part of the setup.
3. I used a variable called 'chosen?' that is owned by each ball to track whether it is still in the bag for the next person to choose. Then the bag-of-balls is created only as all the balls not yet chosen.
4. The code for weighted random choice (when choosing from agentsets) simply has the name of the variable holding the weight as the reporter, but you could use some function such as `rnd:weighted-one-of bag-of-balls [size ^ 2]` if you wanted a more complicated weighting scheme.

Comment: While I agree that, in general, it's nicer to use agentsets than lists when possible, there is an efficiency caveat here: `set my-balls (turtle-set my-balls choice)` is very slow, because NetLogo re-creates the whole agentset every time you call `turtle-set`. In computer science terms, it's O(n), i.e., proportional to the number of agents in the agentset. Adding an item to a list, however (`set my-balls lput choice my-balls`), is very fast: it's effectively O(1), which means that it's not affected by the number of items in the list. Just something to keep in mind for bigger models...

Comment: Also, `(turtle-set nobody)` can be written as [`no-turtles`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#no-turtles).